# why was there a surge in the name 'Tiffany' in the late 1980s?

Tags: names, popularity

Last night Tiffany Porter won a gold medal for Britain in the European Athletics Championships (Womens 100m hurdles).

It came as no surprise to discover that she began life as an American. Apart from her accent, I know of no English girl or woman with the name Tiffany. Apparently there were 10,000 Americans per year named Tiffany in the late 80s and early 90s. (Porter was born in 1987.)

What interests me is why the name, which is an Anglicization of the Greek Theophania, was so popular. Did it have anything to do with 'Breakfast at Tiffany's'?

Is it ever shortened to 'Tiff'?

Comment: Or shortened to "Fanny"?

Comment: @Oldcat I wasn't going to suggest that one.

Comment: Of possible interest: Chapter 6 of *Freakonomics* (2005) is devoted to baby name fashions and how they progress across time and socioeconomic classes. The authors also cover it in an [April 2013 podcast](http://freakonomics.com/2013/04/08/how-much-does-your-name-matter-full-transcript/).

Comment: I named my daughter Tiffany in 1987. I had been watching tv with my dad and yes Brk at Tiffanys is what we were watching. I loved the name! I had been having trouble deciding on a name before that. It was perfect. My dad picked the middle name. My first born beautiful baby girl was proudly named Tiffany Lynne!!

Answer (score 3):

There was a pop singer named Tiffany in the late 80s. She had a few hits.

From Wiki...[Tiffany - American Singer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiffany_%28American_singer%29)

> In 1984, Tiffany was signed to a recording contract by George Tobin
>   who heard a demo tape she recorded.
>
> In 1985, Tiffany appeared on Star Search with Ed McMahon, where she
>   finished second place overall.
>
> In 1986, Tiffany signed a contract that gave Tobin total control over
>   her career. She recorded her first studio album and was signed to a
>   MCA contract. Tiffany's eponymous album, Tiffany, was released in
>   1987. The first single titled "Danny" failed to chart. Following the failure of "Danny", Tiffany went on a nationwide tour titled "The
>   Beautiful You: Celebrating The Good Life Shopping Mall Tour '87". The
>   tour kicked off at the Bergen Mall in Paramus, New Jersey.[4] Her
>   second single, a cover of Tommy James & the Shondells' hit, "I Think
>   We're Alone Now", became a number 1 hit on the Billboard Hot 100
>   list.[5]
>
> Soon she was vying with fellow pop star Debbie Gibson for space on the
>   covers of teen magazines, including Tiger Beat, Bop, and Teen Beat, as
>   well as on television shows on MTV.[citation needed] Her ballad
>   "Could've Been" also peaked at the number one spot on the Billboard
>   charts in February 1988. Tiffany's modified version of the Beatles' "I
>   Saw Her Standing There", retitled "I Saw Him Standing There", peaked
>   at the number seven position on Hot 100.[5] "Feelings of Forever" also
>   saw chart success from the over 4.1 million selling debut.[6] Tiffany
>   also set a record for the youngest female artist to top the Billboard
>   charts with a debut album.[7] Later that year, she toured with New
>   Kids on the Block as the opening act for her concert tour.

Comment: Was she entirely responsible for the surge in Tiffanies? I have to say I haven't heard of her, but then I haven't known any singers since Elvis and the Beatles.

Comment: I have no idea what was in the head of the parents, but I knew of the singer and the timing is ideal.

Comment: And **Breakfast at Tiffany's** was put out in 1961 and had no revival in that period of significance.